# Как получать данные приборов из flightgear?

Tags: java, c++, сокеты

Мне нужно получать данные с приборов самолета из [flightgear](https://www.flightgear.org/) для разработки автопилота.

Какая программа может получить из  flightgear показания с приборов и передать их по сокетам в мое приложение? Или это можно сделать без сторонних программ?

Comment: наверно, вам надо бы пояснить, что именно вы подразумеваете под словом «flightgear», прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Вероятно https://www.flightgear.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.flightgear.org/Telnet_usage

--telnet=socket,bi,5,,5500,tcp в настройках запуска flightgear

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketClient {
    public String host = null;
    public int port = 0;
    public BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    public BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    public PrintWriter out = null;

    public Socket socket = null;
    public Thread readThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
while(true){
    String string = null;
    try {
        string = bufferedReader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(string!=null){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
        }
    });

    public void write(String text){
        /* bufferedWriter.write(text+'\r');
         bufferedWriter.flush();*/
        //out.write(text+"\r");
        out.write(text);
        out.write(System.lineSeparator());
        out.flush();

    }

    public SocketClient(String host,int port){
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host,port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
           // bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        readThread.start();

    }
}
```

Использовать можно вот так:

```
public static void main(String...args){
    SocketClient socketClient = new SocketClient("localhost",5500);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
       String str = scanner.nextLine();
       if(str!=null){
           socketClient.write(str);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Мне лень,можете сделать сами,ну как отредачили пост,у меня один с телефона другой с компа,оба мои :) даю вам согласие,делайте ,что хотите